# Comparison of process name

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock

I write filtering system and use `Winsock2 LSP`. 
In `WSPConnect` I need to compare executable filename of process with harcoded Unicode String.
I do:

```
LPWSTR moduleName = {0};
GetModuleFileNameEx (GetCurrentProcess(),0,moduleName,_MAX_FNAME );

LPWSTR mn = L"redirect.exe";
if (lstrcmp (moduleName, mn) == 0){ ...some code there...}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is going wrong? What result you get? `TCHAR` and `WCHAR` conflict?

Comment: @rajraj, I'm guessing null pointer access on line 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should compare "case-insensitive": [lstrcmpi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647489)
2. You need to pass a correct char array...
3. Also you should always check the result values of function calls!
4. Also you should not use the TCHAR version of `GetModuleFileNameEx` if you explicit use `wchar_t` => `GetModuleFileNameExW`!
5. Also you should use the method [`GetModuleFileNameW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197) if you want to get the name of the current process! This is more reliable!
6. ALso you should use MAX_PATH instead of _MAX_FNAME, because the method might also return the full path!
7. Also be sure that your string is correctly NUL-terminated!
8. Also you must be aware that the returned path might contain the full path, so comparing with the process name does never match...
9. Also you must be aware that the path might contion the short file name! (not in your case, because the name is not longer than 8 characters; but if you compare it with "MyExecutable.exe" you also must compare with the short file name; see [GetShortPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364989)

The code part should now look like:

```
WCHAR moduleName[MAX_PATH+1];
if (GetModuleFileNameW (NULL, moduleName, MAX_PATH) != 0)
{
  moduleName[MAX_PATH] = 0;
  LPWSTR mn = L"redirect.exe";
  int len = lstrlen(moduleName);
  int lenmn = lstrlen(mn);
  if (len > lenmn)
  {
    if (lstrcmpi (&moduleName[len-lenmn], mn) == 0){ ...some code there...}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare storage space, just a pointer is not enough

```
LPWSTR moduleName = {0};
GetModuleFileNameEx (GetCurrentProcess(),0,moduleName,_MAX_FNAME );
```

should be

```
TCHAR moduleName[_MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileNameEx(GetCurrentProcess(), 0, moduleName, _countof(moduleName));
```

and use case-insensitive `lstrcmpi()`.